# No database was installed with Microsoft Dynamics GP

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-gp

I've installed a brand new instance several times of Microsoft Dynamics GP 2010. However, each time I do so, I can't seem to find the database on the local machine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your GP Server machine (ie: where you install SQL Server), you need to run the GP Utilities after install. It's need to complete the install and create a sample company or create a new company. The database should then show up in the SQL Server management tools, etc.